# After expo eject: Cannot get property 'absolutePath' on null object

Tags: android-emulator, expo

I Ejected from Expo since I need to add some native modules to my project. I followed the steps of [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/)
documentation to do that.

The problem is that android emulator on building now is giving an error on build.gradle file:

`"Cannot get property 'absolutePath' on null object"`.

Do you have some recommendation? I never coded in android studio so I´m kinda lost in this problem.

I think the error comes from this function.

```
`def findNdkBuildFullPath() {
  // we allow to provide full path to ndk-build tool
  if (hasProperty('ndk.command')) {
    return property('ndk.command')
  }
  ldNam// or just a path to the containing directory
    if (hasProperty('ndk.path')) {
      def ndkDir = property('ndk.path')
      return new File(ndkDir, getNdkBuie()).`**getAbsolutePath**`()
  }
  if (System.getenv('ANDROID_NDK') != null) {
    def ndkDir = System.getenv('ANDROID_NDK')
    return new File(ndkDir, getNdkBuildName()).`**getAbsolutePath**`()
  }
  def ndkDir = android.hasProperty('plugin') ? android.plugin.ndkFolder :
      plugins.getPlugin('com.android.library').hasProperty('sdkHandler') ?
          plugins.getPlugin('com.android.library').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder() :
          android.ndkDirectory.absolutePath
  if (ndkDir) {
    return new File(ndkDir, getNdkBuildName()).`**getAbsolutePath**`()
  }
  return null
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android studio, click the SDK manager icon in the top left corner. Then on Android SDK, select and download NDK (Native developement kit) LLDB and CMake. This worked for me.